# Do shortcuts and links add to 30,000,000 list item limit?

Tags: 2013, threshold

I would like to know if when you select to use the option "Link to Document" which creates a shortcut to a folder or document or when a "Maintained Link" remains after a document is moved to a records center if those shortcuts and links add to the 30,000,000 item per list limit?  Or do the item limits just refer to physical documents contained within those lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it counts. The document link actually creates a physical ASPX page in your library of the "Link to a Document" content type, which inherits from the Document content type.